# android: execute FragmentPagerAdapter method after view created

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I have an activity that cointains a FragmentPagerAdapter with its view. After the view is created I need to run this method to change textviews (defined in the FragmentPagerAdapter):

```
        public void onPageSelectedCustom(int position) {
        int ValidView;
        FragmentManager myFrag = passedAct.getSupportFragmentManager();
        String name = makeFragmentName(mViewPager.getId(), position);
        ArrayListFragment f = (ArrayListFragment) myFrag.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if(f!=null) {
            ValidView= 1;
            View fragView = f.getView();
            View tv = fragView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("VALID FRAGMENT #" + position);
            Log.d("Fragment", "fragment is valid: " + position);
        } else {
            ValidView= 0;
            Log.d("Fragment", "fragment is not valid: " + position);
        }
}
```

I tried calling `onPageSelectedCustom()` in the FragmentPagerAdapter's constructor however `f` is always null thus never executing the code. I tried working with the activity's `onCreate()`, `onResume()` and `onPostResume()` but they all get called before the Fragment's views are created.

Any ideas of what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` follow a different [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) than `Activity`, so your approach with Activity's lifecycle methods will not work.

From your code, it seems what you want is a way to communicate with the Fragment(s) about which position it is at in the ViewPager. To achieve this you can send your data in `Bundle` from your Activity to your Fragment(s), and then change the Fragment's TextView accordingly from `onCreateView()`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android).